# I'm getting "The system can not find the specified path" error

Tags: python

I'm getting an error 
('The system can not find the specified path', 'A \ *. *').
How to solve this error? I'm not getting what went wrong.

```
def validatepath(status, userpath):
    if status:
        folders = [fol for fol in os.listdir(userpath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(userpath,fol))]
        businesslogic(folders, userpath)
    else:
        print('Invalid Path')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    userPath = input('Enter Directory Path: ')
    status = checkpath(userPath)
    directories = validatepath(status, userPath)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace for the error, not just the message?

Comment: hope you are running the code on Windows machine.

Comment: `return True if os.path.isdir(userPath) else False` => `return os.path.isdir(userPath)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it showing the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
folders = [fol for fol in os.listdir(userpath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(userpath,fol))]
```

Your current code only shows the list of sub-dir of `userpath`. That is the reason why you got an error when you try to call that directory.

Try this:

```
folder = [os.path.join(userpath,fol) for fol in os.listdir(userpath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(userpath,fol))]
```